# Xamarin Forms: Android CardView exception

Tags: android, exception, xamarin.forms, android-cardview, android-theme

In Xamarin Forms 5 I have a BindableLayout containing a Frame with an Image. The ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection.
The problem is that, in Android 10 and 11, SOMETIMES (very often but very random) when adding an item to the ObservableCollection (and hence another Frame with its image shall appear on screen), I receive following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 2: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x10104e2 a=7}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:597)
    at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:127)
    at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:117)
    at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:113)
    at crc64ee486da937c010f4.FrameRenderer.<init>(FrameRenderer.java:24)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.InnerGestureListener.n_onSingleTapUp(Native Method)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.InnerGestureListener.onSingleTapUp(InnerGestureListener.java:79)
    at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:758)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_onTouchEvent(Native Method)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.onTouchEvent(Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:48)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:14309)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3112)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2785)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
```

I tried to investigate and found that the clue is on first line `TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x10104e2 a=7}`, and found that resource id = 0x10104e2 is defined inside Sdk\platforms\android-30\data\res\values\public.xml:

```
<public type="attr" name="colorBackgroundFloating" id="0x010104e2" />
```

And what I understand is that this colorBackgroundFloating is somehow missing in the theme I'm using ("Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"). But trying to fix it in my styles.xml by adding

```
<item name="colorBackgroundFloating">#ffffff</item>
```

is not solving the issue. So I guess I'm not understanding correctly the error.

Does anyone has experience on this (seem somehow common) type of attribute errors?

Comment: Please post some xaml code here, and try to build your project at other Android, for example android 9.0 or 8.1 or others.

Comment: If the problem was a missing resource, I think it would happen all the time. "happens randomly" suggests two different threads trying to access something, at the same time - something isn't in a valid state when `android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList` is called. Given where it happens, that looks to me like a bug in Xamarin Forms on Android, when a Frame contains a CardView. You might need to file an issue at xamarin forms github, with a minimum project to reproduce the bug.

Comment: First, you need to post code here. Show some XAML, and some cs with that ObservableCollection. Post enough code that anyone reading it can see how the touch event causes the add to collection,  Second, as a test, try this (slow) approach, to see if it ever gets the same crash: local variable = new observablecollection; copy all items from your collection property, add item to new collection, set property to the new collection.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I'll try to isolate specific code that easily reproduces the problem as soon as possible.

Comment: @PacoPeps If you still have problem, please update your latest info.